# Access Change property in open (active) form from object

Tags: forms, object, ms-access, timer, reference

I have an issue with Microsoft Access here, which I would like some help solving.

1. Im opening a form [TheActiveWorkingForm].
2. In Form_load I reference an object:
3. Dim obj as testobj

   set obj= new testobj
4. In the referenced object (testobj) I would like to set the timerInterval=200000 on [TheActiveWorkingForm].
5. Returning from the reference object (testobj) to the form [TheActiveWorkingForm].
6. When the 200 seconds has elapsed, then the timer should trigger its event.

   My problem is that it seems that I cant set the timerinterval = 200000 from testobj.

Im aware of the posibility of: me.Timerinterval=200000 in the form. But this doesn't meet my needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the form [TheActiveWorkingForm]'s Has Module property is set to true.  Then in testobj use
`Form_TheActiveWorkingForm.TimerInterval = 200000`